# How to count number of days between date range material picker in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components-android

**How to count the number of days between date range picker**

*I am  Trying but no solution for this please anyone can help me*

I badly need count of days
when user select date range form datepicker range
then set text total count of days .

```
    try {

        String valu1 = String.valueOf(constraintsBuilder.setStart(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        String valu2 = String.valueOf(constraintsBuilder.setEnd(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(valu1);
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(valu2);
        long difference = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());

        Log.i("Testing","days" +difference);
        textView.setText("days" +difference);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

main code is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showDatePicker= findViewById(R.id.showDatepicker);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+06"));
 calendar.clear();

    MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
    builder.setTitleText("Select Date");
  


    final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();

    showDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"DATE_PICKER");

        }
    });


    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {

            showDatePicker.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. And counts days out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
    MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long, Long>> picker = builder.build();
    picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Pair<Long, Long>>() {
        @Override public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long,Long> selection) {
            Long startDate = selection.first;
            Long endDate = selection.second;

            long msDiff = endDate - startDate;
            long daysDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(msDiff);
            

        }
    });
```

Comment: Be aware that `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(msDiff)` is not aware of the actual date, timezones, daylight savings, etc. Because of that, it can have some unintended glitches.

Comment: @Michiel true, but in this scenario it shoudn't be relevant since the 2 selected dates in the picker should have the same conditions.